Strong Completenss vs Finitely Strong Completenss
Definition A logic $\mathcal L$ is strong-complete if for all $\varphi \in \mathcal{L}$ and $\Phi \subseteq \mathcal L$ we have $\Phi \models \varphi$ implies $\Phi \vdash \varphi$.
Definition A logic $\mathcal L$ is finitely-strong-complete if for all $\varphi \in \mathcal{L}$ and finite $\Phi \subseteq \mathcal L$ we have $\Phi \models \varphi$ implies $\Phi \vdash \varphi$.
Can someone provide examples that demonstrate the relationship and differences between these two (apparently) distinct notions? (Like, giving examples of logics that satisfy the latter property but not the former.)
And is there any systematic research on the concept of finite strong completeness?

An example can be found in Priest, Graham (2008). "Many-Valued Modal Logics: A Simple Approach." Review of Symbolic Logic, 1(2), 190-203. In this paper, Priest proves that the tableau for the modal four-valued logic $K_{LP}$ satisfies $\Phi \models \varphi$ implies $\Phi \vdash \varphi$ for all $\varphi$ and finite $\Phi$ in the appropriate language. But he does not show the full-completeness.

The canonical example of this is the logic $L(Q)$ gotten by adding the quantifier $Q\equiv$ "There exist uncountably many" to first-order logic. Improving on earlier work of Vaught, Keisler provided a proof system with respect to which $L(Q)$ is finitely-strong-complete. However, since that proof system is finitary but $L(Q)$ is not compact, it is not strong-complete with respect to that proof system.
(Note that in the abstract Keisler states that Fuhrken showed that the compactness theorem does hold for this logic. Here Keisler refers to a weak form of compactness; to see that full compactness fails for $L(Q)$, just note that $\{c_i\not=c_j: i<j<\omega_1\}\cup\{\neg Qx(x=x)\}$ is obviously finitely satisfiable but not satisfiable. Fully compact logics extending FOL do exist but are quite strange, see Mekler/Shelah.)

Amazing! I guess when you say that $L(Q)$ is not compact, you mean that the compactness theorem doesn't hold in $L(Q)$, right?

Is the "weak form of compactness" countable compactness (if a countable theory is finitely satisfiable, then it is satisfiable)? Is $L(Q)$ countably complete with Keisler's proof system?

@AlexKruckman Yes (I believe) to the first, I'm not sure to the second.

@Taroccoesbrocco That's correct.

TeX's idea of \not Q ($\not Q$) produced a slash tangent to the Q and almost invisible.  I changed \not  to \neg.

@AndreasBlass Yuck, I missed that - thanks!
